# No internet for Ubuntu 19.04 fresh install

Tags: networking, usb, internet

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop without any internet issue. Due to hardware issue (SMTP), the computer was restarting every now and then. During that time, I reinstalled Ubuntu 19.04.

But now, there is no internet, neither through wifi nor through ethernet cable connection.

I have tried live USB of both 18.04 and 19.04. In the live usb also it is all same, there is no wifi or ethernet connection.

I have installed ubuntu by using live dvd as well as live usb but no luck.

I have searched internet and this forum extensively but still could not solve the problem.

It is dual boot along with Windows 10. In Windows 10, there is no network issue at all.

System Configuration:

```
Graphics : Intel® Haswell Desktop
GNOME: 3.28.2
OS Type: 64 bit
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4 
Memory: 3.7 GiB
```

$ sudo lshw -C network

```
[sudo] password for user: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY
       vendor: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:01.0
       version: 31
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=10 mingnt=10
       resources: ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7c10000-f7c101ff memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
```

$ dkms status

```
Command 'dkms' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install dkms
```

Update: I have installed dkms manually. 'dkms status' shows no output.

Then,

$ lspci -n | grep '0200|0280' | awk '{print$3}'

```
13f0:0200
```

$ lspci -nnk

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [1458:5000]
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:2010]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1458:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [1458:5006]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1458:a002]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [1458:5006]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c50] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd B85 Express LPC Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [1458:b005]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev 41)
03:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0200] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0201]
    Kernel modules: sundance
```

$ lspci -vmmnn

```
Slot:   00:00.0
Class:  Host bridge [0600]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [0c00]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [5000]
Rev:    06

Slot:   00:02.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller [0300]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [0412]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [d000]
Rev:    06

Slot:   00:03.0
Class:  Audio device [0403]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [0c0c]
SVendor:    Intel Corporation [8086]
SDevice:    Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [2010]
Rev:    06

Slot:   00:14.0
Class:  USB controller [0c03]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8c31]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [5007]
Rev:    05
ProgIf: 30

Slot:   00:16.0
Class:  Communication controller [0780]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8c3a]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1c3a]
Rev:    04

Slot:   00:1a.0
Class:  USB controller [0c03]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8c2d]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [5006]
Rev:    05
ProgIf: 20

Slot:   00:1b.0
Class:  Audio device [0403]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8c20]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [a002]
Rev:    05

Slot:   00:1c.0
Class:  PCI bridge [0604]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8c10]
Rev:    d5

Slot:   00:1c.3
Class:  PCI bridge [0604]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 82801 PCI Bridge [244e]
Rev:    d5
ProgIf: 01

Slot:   00:1d.0
Class:  USB controller [0c03]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8c26]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [5006]
Rev:    05
ProgIf: 20

Slot:   00:1f.0
Class:  ISA bridge [0601]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: B85 Express LPC Controller [8c50]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    B85 Express LPC Controller [5001]
Rev:    05

Slot:   00:1f.2
Class:  SATA controller [0106]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8c02]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [b005]
Rev:    05
ProgIf: 01

Slot:   00:1f.3
Class:  SMBus [0c05]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8c22]
SVendor:    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd [1458]
SDevice:    8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [5001]
Rev:    05

Slot:   02:00.0
Class:  PCI bridge [0604]
Vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
Device: 82801 PCI Bridge [244e]
Rev:    41
ProgIf: 01

Slot:   03:01.0
Class:  Ethernet controller [0200]
Vendor: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp [13f0]
Device: IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [0200]
SVendor:    Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp [13f0]
SDevice:    IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [0201]
Rev:    31
```

$ sudo lsmod | grep sundance

```
sundance               32768  0
mii                    16384  1 sundance
```

$ sudo modprobe sundance

It shows no output at all

$ uname -a

```
5.0.0-13-generic #14-ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg | tail

```
[   13.689493] audit: type=1400 audit(1566916461.462:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=685 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.689495] audit: type=1400 audit(1566916461.462:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=685 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.691035] audit: type=1400 audit(1566916461.462:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=689 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.691037] audit: type=1400 audit(1566916461.462:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=689 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   39.292281] systemd-journald[328]: File /var/log/journal/579ed6ab24cc48b1bb793a581fec59c9/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   44.258450] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   46.012720] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[   46.466152] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[   46.531176] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
[ 1893.077983] usb 3-8: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

Unplugged the ethernet, switched off, restarted, plugged in ethernet - No effect.

Help needed.

Comment: Just to test something, shutdown, unplug ethernet cable, restart and then plug cable back in.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `dkms status`.

Comment: Edited the question with the above information.

Comment: And what happens if you run `sudo modprobe sundance`? And what is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Added the output of above commands in the post. Thanks.

Comment: You made a typo in `modprobe`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/812520/st201-ethernet-driver-for-linux    The above question and its solution seems somewhat relevant (I am not competent in this matter) but I do not understand what it exactly does and how to do it.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry. corrected. It shows no output.

Comment: Regarding the Debian solution, it is irrelevant, because `sundance` config is enabled in Ubuntu. Please run `dmesg | tail` and post output. The module doesn't load for some reason. `modprobe` shows no error, this is good enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97945/discussion-between-pilot6-and-cosmicraga).

Comment: Id did not work with ubuntu 18.04 (not 18.04.3).. with different kernel..i am going to replace the network card.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and then get your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and go to the manufacturer's web site and look if there's a more current BIOS version. Describe your "SMTP" problem. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them. Report back.

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled in your BIOS?